# In Java I need to remove &#039; from a string

Tags: java, character-encoding

I'm pulling a string in android and it contains `&#039;` in it. I'd rather not use replace all and call the correct method of decoding this string. Could anyone help?
Decoding using UTF-8 doesn't sort the situation.

Comment: *Why* do you not want to use replaceAll or replace? (It's pretty unclear exactly what's going on here.)

Comment: Question is not clear, can you elaborate

Comment: Sorry so I'm getting a JSON object and it contains the ' key in it, but it could really contain any of them as these strings are uploaded by people. In the JSON object that I am retrieving it contains these special characters, I'd rather not have to use replace all for all the special cases so if possible I was hoping for some sort of decoding method.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all.  Post some code so we can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
String s = JSONObject.escape("don't!");
```

Also handles those other pesky characters like backslash.